# How to express the difference between two dates in a human-readable format

Tags: php

If I have two dates - `$end_date` and `$start_date`, how can I express the difference between the two in a format such as "2 Years : 4 Months : 2 Days"?

I know that I can get the difference between the two dates like so:

```
$dif=strtotime($end_date)-strtotime($today);
```

But how can I convert that result into the human-readable format, like that shown above?

Comment: Can you include an example of the desired output?

Comment: @Tim Cooper sure,

This is a simple result - 89337600

Comment: @Ceylo: I actually mean of the formatted timestamp.

Comment: @Tim Cooper sorry my mistake,

2 Years : 4 Months : 2 Days Remaining.

This is what I need to output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Is there a function that converts a date string in a human readable format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763197/php-is-there-a-function-that-converts-a-date-string-in-a-human-readable-format)

Comment: @Tim Cooper no buddy that's not exactly what I wanted.I made a function by myself for that.Thanx.

Comment: If you Google, all the answers will come to you - http://snipplr.com/view/37578/facebook-style-time-ago/ OR http://php.quicoto.com/how-to-calculate-relative-time-like-facebook/

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can format a timestamp:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($end_date)) // for DD-MM-YYYY format
```

Are you looking to calculate the difference between 2 dates, in number days?

**EDIT**: code to find the difference between dates in "XXyear YYmonth ZZday". The code assumes that start and end dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format. If that's not the case for you, please either change them to YYYY-MM-DD format, OR change the arguments to mktime() accordingly.

```
$endDate = '2011-03-01';
$startDate = '2011-02-02';
$daysPerYear = 365;
$daysPerMonth = 30.4;
$diffDay = $diffMonth = $diffYear = 0;

$endDateTs = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($endDate, 5, 2), substr($endDate, 8, 2), substr($endDate, 0, 4));
$startDateTs = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($startDate, 5, 2), substr($startDate, 8, 2), substr($startDate, 0, 4));
$diffDay = ($endDateTs - $startDateTs) / 60 / 60/ 24;   // difference between 2 dates in number of days
$diffYear = floor($diffDay / $daysPerYear); // difference in years
$diffDay = $diffDay % $daysPerYear; // balance days
$diffMonth = floor($diffDay / $daysPerMonth);   // difference in months
$diffDay = ceil($diffDay % $daysPerMonth); // balance days
echo ($diffYear ? $diffYear . 'year ' : '') . ($diffMonth ? $diffMonth . 'month ' : '') . ($diffDay ? $diffDay . 'day' : '');
```

Note: I haven't tested the code for all possible date combinations, including leap year etc. Please feel free to tweak as needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If a coarse difference is enough ("2 years ago"), then you might want to try the [Date_HumanDiff](https://github.com/pear/Date_HumanDiff) PEAR package.

Answer (score 1):

The clean, DRY, professional, modern way to do this is to create two datetime objects and call `diff()`.  The generated diff object will automatically populate year, month, day values for you.

Then you only need to iterate through a lookup array containing your desired units and implode any non-zero results into the plain English output string.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/StLHX))

```
$startDate = '2001-04-20';
$endDate = '2015-11-29';
$diff = (new DateTime($startDate))->diff(new DateTime($endDate));

$lookup = [
    'y' => 'Year',
    'm' => 'Month',
    'd' => 'Day',
];

$elements = [];
foreach ($lookup as $property => $word) {
    if ($diff->$property) {
        $elements[] = "{$diff->$property} $word" . ($diff->$property !== 1 ? 's' : '');
    }
}
echo implode(' : ', $elements);
// 14 Years : 7 Months : 9 Days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_leap_year($year)
{
    if($year % 4 == 0)
    {
        if($year % 100 == 0)
        {
            if($year % 400 == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function calculate_date($now, $end){
    $years = date('Y', strtotime($end)) - date('Y', strtotime($now)) ;
    if($years < 0)
    {
        return "Error: year";
    }
    $mounths = date('m', strtotime($end)) - date('m', strtotime($now)) ;
    if($mounths < 0)
    {
        if($years < 1)
        {
            return "Error: mounth and year";
        }
        else 
        {
            $years --;
            $mounths += 12;
        }
    }
    $days = date('d', strtotime($end)) - date('d', strtotime($now)) ;
    if($days < 0){
        if($mounths < 1)
        {
            if($years < 1)
            {
                return "Error: day, mounth and year";
            }
            else 
            {
                $years --;
                $mounths += 12;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $mounths --;
            switch (date('m', strtotime($now)))
            {
                case 1:
                case 3:
                case 5:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 10:
                case 12:
                    $days +=31;
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 9:
                case 11:
                    $days +=30;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(is_leap_year(date('Y', strtotime($now))))
                    {
                        $days += 29;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $days += 28;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return  $years . " Years : " . $mounths . " Months : " . $days . " Days Remaining.";
}

$end_date = new DateTime('2011-08-05');
$end_date = $end_date->format('d-m-Y');
$today = date('d-m-Y');

$remaining = calculate_date($today, $end_date);

echo $remaining;
```

And if you want to format end_date you can use: 
**date('d-m-Y', strtotime($end_date))**
And after that you can calculate remaining time with calculate_date .