# Time difference between a Date and current Time?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, date

Assume I have a funny video site that shows funny videos to users. Below every video, I want to have a statement that says "5 seconds ago", "31 minutes ago", "Yesterday", "2 days ago" based on a timestamp of the video and the current time.

The timestamp that I have is in the format: `2011-10-17 07:08:00`.

I'm not too good with dates, but I'm guessing that I need to find the difference between the 2 date/time in seconds, then decide if its between 0sec & 60sec to display in seconds, or between 60sec & 3600sec to display in minutes, or between 3600sec & 3600x24sec to display in hours, between 3600x24sec & 3600x24x2sec to display yesterday, and so on... I believe I should be using `strtotime()` but I cant seem to find the current time as those solutions I found used `new date()` which does not seem to work!

How can I do this?

Btw, side question, when I insert `2011-10-17, 7:08PM EDT` into a MySQL timestamp column, it gets converted to `2011-10-17 07:08:00` which is AM. How can I get it to be stored in the correct AM/PM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to express the difference between two dates in a human-readable format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542931/how-to-express-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-a-human-readable-format)

Comment: I love the first sentence. Is the idea that the funny video site is playing funny videos integral to the problem? :)

Comment: people seems to be downvoting alot these days

Comment: I assume this question was collecting dvs because it is a requirements dump.  Saying that you found `strtotime()` and `new date()` doesn't really narrow the task down to a specific failure point.  This requires answers to provide a fully built tutorial/solution that handles many different human-readable possibilities.  AND your question is asking multiple questions.  For such an old page with a common/basic title, this page has proven unhelpful to quite a lot of researchers and the accepted answer doesn't get close to delivering what you've asked for.  **Needs More Focus**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) functions of php.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2011-10-17 07:08:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

From here on you can use some if-statements to output the time difference in another format (seconds, minutes, hours, month, etc.) depending on the actual time difference! The formats for the output are to find [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily use the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) functions of MySQL. Both together tell you exactly how much time has passed.