# How to use timespan in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, timespan

I've got 2 fields to populate: how many times the page is called per 15 minutes and per hour.

Following fields are DateTime in MySql:

```
$lastAccess15m=$row['lastAccess15m'];
$lastAccessHour=$row['lastAccessHour'];
```

And these fields are ints:

```
$accessPer15m=$row['accessPer15m'];
$accessPerHour=$row['accessPerHour'];
```

I want to compare current time with `$lastAccess15`, and if the time distance is larger than 15 minutes, set the value of `$lastAccess15` to current time, and reset `$accessPer15m`, otherwise, increment `$accessPer15m`. The same goes for `$lastAccessHour` and `$accessPerHour`, after which those values have to be saved to mysql database.

How do I get the timespan between current time and $accessPer15m in minutes/hours?

Comment: Have you at least tried to [read the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time difference between a Date and current Time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807241/time-difference-between-a-date-and-current-time)

Comment: @lanzz I want to do this in entirely PHP if possible. There are many columns in the table I'm working with, and I'm selecting them all with select * from....; if I use select timediff(...) as `oeu`,....  I feel that will result in a rather ugly code

Comment: @serentei:timespan between two times means difference between times?

Comment: @Suresh yes, this is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

[MySQL datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html):

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

**To compare both of them**, you need to convert one and them perform the comparison:

```
$phpDateFromMysql = strtotime( $mysqldate );

$mySqlDateFromPHP = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate);
```

**The easiest way** is to convert the Mysql value to time() and perform the comparison:

See this [working Example](http://codepad.org/2izBsnVL)!

```
<?php

// compare if the value from $lastAccess15 is +15min in relation to the current time
$lastAccess15 = '2012-06-01 00:00:00';

$phpDateFromMysql = strtotime( $lastAccess15 );

if ($phpDateFromMysql - $lastAccess15 > 900) {
    $lastAccess15 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
}

echo $lastAccess15;
?>
```

**Note:** Inside the `if` statement you can perform the remaining of your operations, and even add an `else` clause to perform some operations if the time isn't > 15min (like the increment you where referring to).

---

**Relevant reading material:**

PHP [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

PHP [elseif/else if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) control structure

Answer (score 2):

In SQL also SELECT `NOW() as current_timestamp` (alongwith your other selections).

In PHP:

```
if ((strtotime($row['current_timestamp']) - strtotime($row['lastAccess15m'])) > 900) {

 // your code 
}
```

`strtotime` converts TimeStamp to seconds, and then you can compare time difference to 900 seconds. (15 minutes).

Comment: to get the current time in seconds in PHP, you can call `time()` - no need to do it in SQL just to get it to PHP.

Comment: Current time of php time() and the value on SQL entry might not be same? Especially if php file is making connection to remote SQL. By using NOW() in SQL, you are using same time frame as that used on the 'lastAccess15m' field. (I think so at least).