# Human-readable duration between two UNIX timestamps

Tags: c++, date, unix, unix-timestamp, duration

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two UNIX timestamps (i.e. seconds since 1970). I want to say e.g. "3 years, 4 months, 6 days, etc" but I don't know how to account for leap years and months of different durations. Surely this is a solved problem..?

This is different to other questions which want to express an approximate duration in one unit that has a fixed/homogeneous duration (e.g. 3 hours, or 7 weeks, etc.). Results for 1. Jan to 1. Feb would be "1 month" and results for 1. Feb to 1. Mar would also be "1 month" even though the number of days are different.

I want to express the complete duration precisely but in years/months/days/hours/minutes. Solutions in C++ would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if "3 years, 4 months, 6 days" has a useful meaning. The same interval may be expressed differently and vice versa depending on where it is in the year or century. For example it is one month from 1. Feb to 1. Mar but also from 1. Jan to 1. Feb.

Comment: Do you want to parse arbitrary time expressions and then subtract, or do you want to express the result of the subtraction in human terms? If the latter, do you want real calendar months, or fixed 30-day months?

Comment: For the latter, I find multiple duplicates for PHP; if you can live with the nausea, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069521/how-to-display-time-difference-in-a-human-readable-format-in-php

Comment: @Henry. Exactly. The interval will differ depending on the specifics of the dates. How is that not a useful meaning?

Comment: @tripleee. I want to express the result of the subtraction in human terms. The reason this is different to the duplicates you referenced is that they just want to report in one unit, e.g. "2 weeks", "3 years", etc. whereas I want to account specifically for the full/precise interval in total. (i.e. years, months, days, hours, etc.)

Comment: See the multiple other duplicates, or specify how yours is different. (Requiring a solution in e.g. Python or Ruby might be a viable workaround; but do note that asking for pointers to existing code is generally frowned upon.) If you want to keep this question from attracting close votes, you should probably [edit] it to clarify it, and include more details.

Comment: what language do you use ? for java, many answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina, in C++ is preferable. Thanks, but none of that Java stuff you referenced was helpful...

Comment: @JohnElliotV - _The interval will differ depending on the specifics of the dates. How is that not a useful meaning?_ I would (do) argue that such a meaning is not useful on account of the fact that it is not unambiguous. Up to and including weeks, each unit of time is exact and has just one meaning. Offering precision down to the minute seems without purpose if the user is then able to make a trivial error of calculation due to leap years and months of different duration. While your aim is stated very clearly, this still seems to be an X/Y problem to me. What are you trying to measure/achieve?

Comment: @enhzflep - the meaning is not ambiguous. It's very specific and precise. For any given date range there is one unambiguous and well-defined result. As for what I'm trying to measure/achieve: I'm creating a clock (on an Arduino board) for my mate that says how long he has been married for as an anniversary gift for his wife. I.e. "You have been happily married for 1 year, 3 months, 3 days, and 7 minutes..."

Comment: Ok, when the start date is fixed, I agree it is meaningful.

Comment: @JohnElliotV - I too agree with the sentiment expressed by Henry and no longer see there being scope for ambiguity (a) since the start date is fixed and (b) since it's something that there will be just a single instance of. I think it's a really sweet idea. . The extra detail causes me to think of a few (perhaps pertinent) points. Even the lowliest of Arduinos have a fair amount of PROGMEM and a clock should need virtually none of it for normal operation. There's only 14 calendars - 1 for a year starting on each day of the week and then a further 7 for leap years. I'd consider <cont>

Comment: <from prev> computing first the number of mins, hours, days or weeks and then use this information in combination with a look-up table to compute the value to be displayed. It's 5am and I should have gone to bed hours ago. I'll have more of a think after I've slept. For reference, do you know which board you'll be implementing the clock with and therefore, how much memory you'll have to play with? Also, is there a chance you'd be using an lcd with an sdcard on the back as some have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the older date, use the Leap Year formula to start counting the number of days from Unix start date, Jan1st 1970, to your first timestamp

(For leap seconds, dunno if you need to get that precise, hopefully will be out-of-scope?)

Leap year calculated by constraining date to after 1600AD and
the algorithm for the Gregorian Calendar from:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year of

`if year modulo 400 is 0
       then is_leap_year
    else if year modulo 100 is 0
       then not_leap_year
    else if year modulo 4 is 0
      then is_leap_year
    else
      not_leap_year`

If a year is a Leap Year, then there are 29days in Feb, else 28days

Now you know the month, day_of_month, year for the 1st variable

Next, another set of counts of days to the 2nd timestamp, using the Leap Year formula till you get to the 2nd timestamp.

```
typedef struct {
  int year;
  int month;
  int dayOfMonth;
} date_struct;

static int days_in_month[2][13] = {
  {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
  {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
};

int isLeapYear(int year) {
  int value;
  value = year;

  //if year modulo 400 is 0
  //   then is_leap_year
  value = year % 400;
  if(value == 0) return 1;

  //else if year modulo 100 is 0
  //   then not_leap_year
  value = year % 100;
  if(value == 0) return 0;

  //else if year modulo 4 is 0
  //   then is_leap_year
  value = year % 4;
  if(value == 0) return 1;

  //else
  //   not_leap_year
  return 0;
}

date_struct addOneDay(date_struct ds, int isLeapYear){
  int daysInMonth;

  ds.dayOfMonth++;

  //If the month is February test for leap year and adjust daysInMonth
  if(ds.month == 2) {
    daysInMonth = days_in_month[isLeapYear][ds.month];
  } else {
    daysInMonth = days_in_month[0][ds.month];
  }

  if(ds.dayOfMonth > daysInMonth) {
    ds.month++;
    ds.dayOfMonth = 1;
    if(ds.month > 12) {
      ds.year += 1;
      ds.month = 1;
    }
  }
  return ds;
}

long daysBetween(date_struct date1, date_struct date2){
  long result = 0l;
  date_struct minDate = min(date1, date2);
  date_struct maxDate = max(date1, date2);

  date_struct countingDate;
  countingDate.year = minDate.year;
  countingDate.month = minDate.month;
  countingDate.dayOfMonth = minDate.dayOfMonth;

  int leapYear = isLeapYear(countingDate.year);
  int countingYear = countingDate.year;

  while(isLeftDateSmaller(countingDate,maxDate)) {
    countingDate = addOneDay(countingDate,leapYear);
    //if the year changes while counting, check to see if
    //it is a new year
    if(countingYear != countingDate.year) {
      countingYear = countingDate.year;
      leapYear = isLeapYear(countingDate.year);
    }

    result++;
  }

  return result;
}
```

(I wrote an open source program that gives the difference between two calendar dates, in C/C++. Its source code, some that I posed above, might help give you inspiration for your own solution, or maybe you can adapt some of it, too http://mrflash818.geophile.net/software/timediff/ )

Comment: If you are allowed use the Boost C++ libraries, Boost has a library that might work for you, too: boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp

Answer (score 4):

Using this [free, open-source C++11/14 date/time library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), this problem can be solved very simply, with very high-level syntax.  It leverages the C++11 `<chrono>` library.

As relatively few people are familiar with how my [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) works, I will go through how to do this in painstaking detail, piece by piece.  Then at the end I put it all together packaged up in a neat function.

To demonstrate it, I will assume some helpful using declarations to cut down on the verbosity:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
```

And it also helps to have some example [UNIX timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to work with.

```
auto t0 = sys_days{1970_y/7/28} + 8h + 0min + 0s;
auto t1 = sys_days{2016_y/4/2} + 2h + 34min + 43s;
std::cout << t0.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
std::cout << t1.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
```

This will print out:

```
18000000
1459564483
```

This indicates that 1970-07-28 08:00:00 UTC is 18000000 seconds after the epoch and 2016-04-02 02:34:43 UTC is 1459564483 seconds after the epoch.  This all neglects leap seconds.  That is consistent with the way [UNIX timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) work, and consistent with the operation of `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`.

Next it is convenient to "coarsen" these timestamps with seconds precision down to timestamps with a precision of days (number of days since the epoch).  This is done with this code:

```
auto dp0 = floor<days>(t0);
auto dp1 = floor<days>(t1);
```

`dp0` and `dp1` have type `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>>`, which is a whopping mouth-full!  Isn't `auto` *nice*!  There is a `typedef` called `date:: sys_days` that is a handy shortcut for the type of `dp0` and `dp1`, so you don't ever have to type out the ugly form.

Next it is handy to convert `dp0` and `dp1` to `{year, month, day}` structures.  There is such a structure with the type `date::year_month_day` which will implicitly convert from `sys_days`:

```
year_month_day ymd0 = dp0;
year_month_day ymd1 = dp1;
```

This is a very simple structure with `year()`, `month()` and `day()` getters.

It is also handy to have the time since midnight for each of these [UNIX timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  That is easily obtained by subtracting the days-resolution `time_point` from seconds-resolution `time_point`:

```
auto time0 = t0 - dp0;
auto time1 = t1 - dp1;
```

`time0` and `time1` have type `std::chrono::seconds` and represent the seconds past the start of the day for `t0` and `t1`.

To verify where we are, it is handy to output what we have so far:

```
std::cout << ymd0 << ' ' << make_time(time0) << '\n';
std::cout << ymd1 << ' ' << make_time(time1) << '\n';
```

which outputs:

```
1970-07-28 08:00:00
2016-04-02 02:34:43
```

So far so good.  We have two [UNIX timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) divided up into their human readable components (at least year, month and day).  The function `make_time` shown in the print statement above takes `seconds` and converts it into a `{hours, minutes, seconds}` structure.

Ok, but so far all we've done is take [UNIX timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and convert them to field types.  Now for the difference part...

To take the *human-readable* difference we start with the big units and subtract them.  And then if the next smallest units are not subtractible (if the subtraction would produce a negative result), then the bigger-unit subtraction is too big by one.  Stay with me, code+example is clearer than human language:

```
auto dy = ymd1.year() - ymd0.year();
ymd0 += dy;
dp0 = ymd0;
t0 = dp0 + time0;
if (t0 > t1)
{
    --dy;
    ymd0 -= years{1};
    dp0 = ymd0;
    t0 = dp0 + time0;
}
std::cout << dy.count() << " years\n";
std::cout << ymd0 << ' ' << make_time(time0) << '\n';
std::cout << ymd1 << ' ' << make_time(time1) << '\n';
```

This outputs:

```
45 years
2015-07-28 08:00:00
2016-04-02 02:34:43
```

First we take the difference between the `year` fields of `ymd1` and `ymd0` and store this in the variable `dy` which has type `date::years`.  Then we add `dy` back to `ymd0` and recompute the serial `time_point`s `dp0` and `t0`.  If it turns out that `t0 > t1` then we have added one too many years (because the month/day of `ymd0` occurs later in the year than that of `ymd1`).  So we subtract a year and recompute.

Now we have the difference in years, and we have reduced the problem to finding the difference in `{months, days, hours, minutes, seconds}` and this delta is guaranteed to be less than 1 year.

This is the basic formula for the whole problem!  Now we just need to rinse and repeat with the smaller units:

```
auto dm =  ymd1.year()/ymd1.month() - ymd0.year()/ymd0.month();
ymd0 += dm;
dp0 = ymd0;
t0 = dp0 + time0;
if (t0 > t1)
{
    --dm;
    ymd0 -= months{1};
    dp0 = ymd0;
    t0 = dp0 + time0;
}
std::cout << dm.count() << " months\n";
std::cout << ymd0 << ' ' << make_time(time0) << '\n';
std::cout << ymd1 << ' ' << make_time(time1) << '\n';
```

The first line of this example deserves extra attention because a lot is going on here.  We need to find the difference between `ymd1` and `ymd0` in units of months.  Just subtracting `ymd0.month()` from `ymd1.month()` only works if `ymd1.month() >= ymd0.month()`.  But `ymd1.year()/ymd1.month()` creates a `date::year_month` type.  These types are "time points", but with a precision of a month.  One can subtract these types and get `months` as a result.

Now the same formula is followed:  Add the difference of months back to `ymd0`, recompute `dp0` and `t0`, and discover if you've added one too many months.  If so, add one less month.  The above code outputs:

```
8 months
2016-03-28 08:00:00
2016-04-02 02:34:43
```

Now we're down to finding the difference of `{days, hours, minutes, seconds}` between two dates.

```
auto dd = dp1 - dp0;
dp0 += dd;
ymd0 = dp0;
t0 = dp0 + time0;
if (t0 > t1)
{
    --dd;
    dp0 -= days{1};
    ymd0 = dp0;
    t0 = dp0 + time0;
}
std::cout << dd.count() << " days\n";
std::cout << ymd0 << ' ' << make_time(time0) << '\n';
std::cout << ymd1 << ' ' << make_time(time1) << '\n';
```

Now the interesting thing about `sys_days`s is that they are really good at day-oriented arithmetic.  So instead of dealing with field types like `year_month_day` or `year_month`, we work with `sys_days` at this level.  We just subtract `dp1 - dp0` to get the difference in `days`.  Then we add that to `dp0`, and recreate `ymd0` and `t0`.  Check if `t0 > t1` and if so, we've added one too many `days` so we back off by one day.  This code outputs:

```
4 days
2016-04-01 08:00:00
2016-04-02 02:34:43
```

Now we are just down to finding the difference between two time stamps in terms of `{hours, minutes, seconds}`.  This is really simple, and where `<chrono>` shines.

```
auto delta_time = time1 - time0;
if (time0 > time1)
    delta_time += days{1};
auto dt = make_time(delta_time);
std::cout << dt.hours().count() << " hours\n";
std::cout << dt.minutes().count() << " minutes\n";
std::cout << dt.seconds().count() << " seconds\n";
t0 += delta_time;
dp0 = floor<days>(t0);
ymd0 = dp0;
time0 = t0 - dp0;
std::cout << ymd0 << ' ' << make_time(time0) << '\n';
std::cout << ymd1 << ' ' << make_time(time1) << '\n';
```

We can just subtract `time0` from `time1`.  Both `time1` and `time0` have type `std::chrono::seconds` and their difference has the same type.  If it turns out that `time0 > time1` (as in this example), we need to add a `day`.  Then we can add the difference back and recompute `time0`, `dp0` and `ymd0` to check out our work.  We should get the same timestamp as `t1` now.  This code outputs:

```
18 hours
34 minutes
43 seconds
2016-04-02 02:34:43
2016-04-02 02:34:43
```

This is all a very long-winded explanation for this code:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

struct ymdhms
{
    date::years          y;
    date::months         m;
    date::days           d;
    std::chrono::hours   h;
    std::chrono::minutes min;
    std::chrono::seconds s;
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ymdhms& x)
{
    os << x.y.count()   << " years "
       << x.m.count()   << " months "
       << x.d.count()   << " days "
       << x.h.count()   << " hours "
       << x.min.count() << " minutes "
       << x.s.count()   << " seconds";
    return os;
}

using second_point =
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds>;

ymdhms
human_readable_difference(second_point t1, second_point t0)
{
    using namespace date;
    auto dp0 = floor<days>(t0);
    auto dp1 = floor<days>(t1);
    year_month_day ymd0 = dp0;
    year_month_day ymd1 = dp1;
    auto time0 = t0 - dp0;
    auto time1 = t1 - dp1;
    auto dy = ymd1.year() - ymd0.year();
    ymd0 += dy;
    dp0 = ymd0;
    t0 = dp0 + time0;
    if (t0 > t1)
    {
        --dy;
        ymd0 -= years{1};
        dp0 = ymd0;
        t0 = dp0 + time0;
    }
    auto dm =  ymd1.year()/ymd1.month() - ymd0.year()/ymd0.month();
    ymd0 += dm;
    dp0 = ymd0;
    t0 = dp0 + time0;
    if (t0 > t1)
    {
        --dm;
        ymd0 -= months{1};
        dp0 = ymd0;
        t0 = dp0 + time0;
    }
    auto dd = dp1 - dp0;
    dp0 += dd;
    t0 = dp0 + time0;
    if (t0 > t1)
    {
        --dd;
        dp0 -= days{1};
        t0 = dp0 + time0;
    }
    auto delta_time = time1 - time0;
    if (time0 > time1)
        delta_time += days{1};
    auto dt = make_time(delta_time);
    return {dy, dm, dd, dt.hours(), dt.minutes(), dt.seconds()};
}
```

Which can be exercised like this:

```
int
main()
{
    std::cout << human_readable_difference(second_point{1459564483s},
                                           second_point{18000000s}) << '\n';
}
```

and outputs:

```
45 years 8 months 4 days 18 hours 34 minutes 43 seconds
```

The algorithms behind all this are all public domain and neatly collected and explained here:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

I would like to emphasize that this question is a good but complicated question because of the non-uniformity of units such as years and months.  The most effective way to deal with a question like this is to have low-level tools capable of abstracting away the complicated low-level arithmetic with higher-level syntax.

As an added verification, this:

```
std::cout << human_readable_difference(sys_days{feb/11/2000} + 9h + 21min + 6s,
                                       sys_days{jul/12/1900} + 15h + 24min + 7s) << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
99 years 6 months 29 days 17 hours 56 minutes 59 seconds
```

which is identical to the output reported in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36346799/576911) that reports what [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) outputs. As a bonus, the syntax here does not -- *and can not* -- suffer from endian ambiguity (m/d/y vs d/m/y). Admittedly this involved a little luck in that [Wolfram's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) output is reported using the "America/New_York" timezone, and for these two timestamps the UTC offset is the same (so the timezone offset does not factor in).

If timezone actually does matter, an [additional software layer](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) on top of this is required.

Answer (score -1):

Re: "*surely this is a solved problem?*"

This problem appears to be be solved, if **Wolfram Alpha** is correct.  It seems WA doesn't publicly provide their method, and their site deliberately makes screen-scraping difficult, but it *has* a method, which is available as an online "black box".

To see that black box in action, go to [**Wolfram Alpha**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), and eEnter two dates, separated by a "to", for example:

```
7/12/1900 to 2/11/2000
```

Outputs:

> 99 years 6 months 30 days

Times of day also:

```
7/12/1900 3:24:07pm  to 2/11/2000 9:21:06am
```

Outputs:

> 99 years 6 months 29 days 17 hours 56 minutes 59 seconds

Note that Wolfram assumes a default EST timezone.  Locations too, can be input, here's the same numeric range the latter example but in different locations and timezones:

```
7/12/1900 3:24:07pm in Boston to 2/11/2000 9:21:06am in Hong Kong
```

The output is different from the previous answer by 13 hours:

> 99 years 6 months 29 days 4 hours 56 minutes 59 seconds

Comment: Corrected a gruesome mis-pasting, where that 2nd to last 'returns' was for a *different* query.   All queries and returned results are now what WA output.