# Date and Time 24 hour format Get Difference in PhP

Tags: php, datetime

I have two dates in 24 hour format

```
$fulldate_hour_start    = "2013-11-11 18:16:00 ";
$fulldate_hour_end      = "2013-11-11 23:30:00 ";
```

and I subtracted them using this

```
$Hours = number_format((((strtotime($fulldate_hour_end) - strtotime($fulldate_hour_start)) / 60) / 60),2);
```

and the result is 5 hours and 23 minutes. it should be 5 hours and 14 minutes. What is my error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2013-11-11 18:16:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2013-11-11 23:30:00");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "difference " . $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dividing by 3600 to convert from seconds to hours and then using `number_format` to render the result with two decimal places.

The result of the expression was:

```
5.23
```

Which is indeed approximately 5 hours and 14 minutes. (Remember that an hour has 60 minutes.)

Rather than do this, you should keep the value in seconds, and then use a [function to convert it to a human readable format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1763197/1068283). One possibility is [`date_diff`](http://www.php.net/date_diff); the linked SO question has many others.

Answer (score 0):

Since an hour consist of 60, not 100, minutes, 5.23 hours is 5 hours and 13.8 minutes. The 0.2 hour mismatch is due to rounding the real value to two decimals to get 0.23.

```
0.23 * 60 = 13.8
```