# Difference of hours between two times having format [H:i]

Tags: php

I have two hours format value

> 1) [start_time] => 07:30
>       2) [end_time] => 13:50

I want difference in hours between this two time.
For this case 07:30 to 13:50 it's difference of 6.00 hours.

so i need ans 6.00

Comment: what you have tried so far? please add code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date and Time 24 hour format Get Difference in PhP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899519/date-and-time-24-hour-format-get-difference-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTime classes, and use the `diff()` method. Create two DateTime objects with the different times, and apply `diff()` on one of them, with the other as the argument. Then you just print the `format()` which is applicable, which in your example is `%H:%I`.

```
$first = new DateTime("7:30");
$second = new DateTime("13:30");

$diff = $second->diff($first);
echo $diff->format("%H:%I"); // 06:00
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/gV7jf)
- [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)
- [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)